# browser reflow or not reflow?

Tags: performance, rendering, google-chrome-devtools, reflow

My question is simple,

**why I can see any reflow on chrome devtool timeline when I try to get the offset position of a element ?**

I've just read this =>

> offsetTop, offsetLeft, offsetWidth, offsetHeight,
>   scrollTop/Left/Width/Height, ClientTop/Left/Width/Height,
>   getComputedStyle(), or currentStyle in IE
>
> All of these above are essentially requesting style information about
>   a node, and any time you do it, the browser has to give you the most
>   up-to-date value. In order to do so, it needs to apply all scheduled
>   changes, flush the queue, bite the bullet and do the reflow.

So I open my chrome devtool timeline but I didn't see any recalculate style (purple stuff) when I try this :

```
element.offsetHeight;
```

The only way to see some rendering is to change the style of the element :

```
element.style.left = element.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
```

I was expecting to see a reflow everytime I try to get the scroll Top of the window but no :/

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 1):

I (maybe) found the answer thanks to Christoph

[How can I visualize that reading element.offsetWidth causes a recalc/reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084135/how-can-i-visualize-that-reading-element-offsetwidth-causes-a-recalc-reflow?rq=1)

Ok so if I have understood:

The offsetHeight will flush the rendering queue, if the style information isn't modify (for him and his parents) Then the browser already has the inforamtion and doesn't make a reflow :)

That why we don't see any reflow :)